# How to calculate convolution of two logarithmic function, i.e. $\int \ln(\tau)\ln{(x-\tau)}d\tau$

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, closed-form

Here I have a problem to calculate the probability density function (PDF) of the sum of two independent random variables (RVs), $Z_0,Z_1$, and the PDF of $Z_0,Z_1$ are as follow:

$$f_{Z_0}(x)=\frac{1}{a}\ln\frac{a}{x},\quad x\in(0,a]$$
$$f_{Z_1}(x)=\frac{1}{b}\ln\frac{b}{x},\quad x\in(0,b]$$

where $a,b$ are two positive constants.

PDF of the sum of independent RVs is the convolution of PDF of each component RV. I considered characteristic function (Fourier Transform) and direct convolution. However, how to get the closed-form expression of $\displaystyle \int_0^{x} \ln(\tau)\ln{(x-\tau)}d\tau$ ?

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^{x} \ln(\tau)\ln{(x-\tau)}d\tau=\\\int_0^{1} \ln(x\sigma)\ln{(x-x\sigma)}d(x\sigma)=$$
$$\int_0^{1}(\ln(x)+\ln(\sigma))(\ln(x)+\ln{(1-\sigma)})xd\sigma=$$
$$x\ln^2(x)+x\ln(x)\int_0^1\ln(\sigma)d\sigma+x\ln(x)\int_0^1\ln(1-\sigma)d\sigma+x\int_0^{1}\ln(\sigma)\ln{(1-\sigma})d\sigma=\\
x\ln^2(x)-2x\ln(x)+(2-\frac{\pi^2}6)x$$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed derivation, Daoust. But for my problem, I hope to get the closed-form expression of the piece-wise PDF for $f_{Z_0}\ast f_{Z_1}$. For example, how to obtain closed-form like $\int_{x-b}^a \ln{\tau}\ln{(x-\tau)}d\tau$?

Comment: You didn't state it clearly. For these general bounds, there is no closed formula unless you allow the Li integral.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your help. At least I learn that there is no closed-form for such convolution. Whether there exists upper bound or lower bound closed formula for $\int_{x-b}^a \ln{\tau}\ln{(x-\tau)}d\tau$, for I wanna calculate the upper bound probability of $X>\sigma$. What I consider is to get a tight bound of $\int_{\sigma}^{\infty}f_{S}(x)dx$. I have tried Chebyshev's inequality, but it is not tight enough.

Comment: Get the integral with Wolfram and accept the $Li$ function or look for approximations of it.