# Fourier transform of mod of a function

Tags: integration, modules, fourier-transform

How to calculate the Fourier transform of
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{|x+c||x-c|}$$
I tried using
" [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform+calculator"](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform+calculator%22), but I don't get any results, please help me.

Comment: Is it in dimension $1$ ?

Comment: You can easily restrict to $c=1$. Then you might get the result by writing
$$
\mathcal F f = \mathcal F(|x^2-1|^{-1}) = \mathcal F(\mathrm{sign}(x^2-1)\,(x^2-1)^{-1})
$$
Now remarking that $\mathrm{sign}(x^2-1) = 1 - 2\, \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}$ you obtain
$$
\mathcal F f = \mathcal F((x^2-1)^{-1}) -  2\, \mathcal F(\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}\,(x^2-1)^{-1})
$$
and you can get the first Fourier transform by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909722/how-to-find-the-inverse-fourier-transform-of-fw-frac1w2-a2 and the second by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform (Formula 501)

Comment: Depends on how you define $1/|x^2 - c^2|$. If you take it to be the distributional derivative of
$$f(x) = \frac 1 {2 c}
 \ln \left| \frac {x - c} {x + c} \right|
 \operatorname {sgn} \frac {x - c} {x + c}$$
(which is a valid regularization of the ordinary function $1/|x^2 - c^2|$), then the FT is $-i w \mathcal F[f](w)$. There is a closed form in terms of the sine integral and cosine integral functions.

Answer (score 1):

Almost an answer, but with remaining questions...

First of all, this issue has to be considered in the sense of distributions.

Let us first concentrate on the F.T. of $1/|x|$ which is (see formula (2) in the detailed answer of @Sangchul Lee to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1522986):

$$\mathcal F (\tfrac{1}{|x|})=- \log|\xi| - (\gamma + \log(2\pi))\delta \tag{1}$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Out of (1), it is immediate to obtain $\mathcal F (1/|x-c|)$ and $\mathcal F (1/|x+c|)$; it remains to convolve them, because a product is transformed into a convolution by $\mathcal F$.

Now, can we obtain a final **closed form** ? Maybe by working on the result obtained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/944960) ?

Using DFT, I have obtained the following ogival curve for this Fourier transform (code below); I will continue to work on this question ...

[image]

Matlab code:

```
x=-20:0.011:20;
c=1; % other values give almost the same shape
s=1./abs(x-c);u=fftshift(abs(fft(s)));
s=1./abs(x+c);v=fftshift(abs(fft(s)));
w=conv(u,v,'same');
plot(x,1e-7*w);
```

**Remark:** Wolfram Alpha, to the question phrased in this way: FourierTransform[1/Abs[x]], does provide an answer:

$$\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int \tfrac{1}{|x|} e^{i\omega x}dx=-\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}\left(\log(|\omega|)+\gamma\right)$$

The normalization factor $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$ isn't an issue, we know it (it is one of the "avatars" of the Fourier Transform); **but where have the $2 \pi$ and the dirac $\delta$ gone?** ...

Comment: See the remark I just added.

Comment: Thanks for your great effort, waiting for your more updated answer @Jean Marie

Comment: It does not seems there should be a Dirac delta (see for example my computations here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723136/the-fourier-transform-of-1-p3/3724502#3724502). The $2\pi$ in the $\ln$ also depends on the normalization of the Fourier transform (since $\ln(2π x) = \ln(2\pi) + \ln(x)$)

Comment: Very interesting ! Yes, you are right: the $2 \pi $ term depends on the normalization, I should have thought about it.

Comment: A way to be sure that there is no Dirac delta involved is just to remark that since $1/|x|$ is of homogeneity $-1$, its Fourier transform will be of homogeneity $1-1 = 0$ (if we are in dimension $1$)

Comment: New for me and interesting...

Comment: Looking at the answer of Sangchul Lee you are refeering to, he is correct. But he is giving the Fourier transform of the $\ln$, in which you have a Dirac delta appearing. When you take the Fourier transform of his formula, you get what you tell, but replacing the delta by $\widehat{\delta_0} = 1$. So you just forget that ;)

Comment: In general, the convolution of two distributions with unbounded supports is undefined.

Comment: @Maxim I recognize that I have some "holes" in my knowledge of distributions. Maybe, LL 3.14, could you answer ?